# How to view only opened files in Atom sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

In Atom editor, I can add a project folder which I would see in the sidebar. Whenever I open any file in Atom, the reference to the same file can be seen in the sidebar, but that is seen along with the folder hierarchy.

Please see: [Atom Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UekRE.png)

As visible in the above image, I can see the open file 'Combined Plan.txt' in the sidebar but along with it, I also see the container folders and sub-folders. Is there any way by which, in the sidebar, I could see a list of only the open files?

For example, look at this screenshot from VS Code: [VS Code - Open Editors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xj4k.png)

As visible in this image, I can see only the individual names of the open files in the 'Open Editors' section, even though I haven't opened any folder.
So similarly, can I have only the open file names displayed in the Atom sidebar without having the folder details displayed?